# Designing a high perfomance numeric function in c++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am building on a numeric C++ library that aims in achieving high performance computations (off course double-types will be the main arithmetic type). Therefore i am making heavy use of template metaprogramming. Describing what i want to build and when my "problem" occurs can be cumbersome to read so i have created a toy example that "simulates" to what i want to do.

Consider that i want to design a method that it takes a container, scales its contents against some constants and returns the sum of the scaled numbers. For simplicity, lets assume that i want it to work on containers of size 3. The constants can vary so when programming, the programmer(user of the lib) will have to supply them. The problem is that these constants can be single or double precision, something that can be used as template arguments.

Though, on the other hand, i would like the compiler to emmit code that will be as if i have hard-coded the constants.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace std;

template<class T, class Coefs>
struct scale_add{

    Coefs coefs;    

    template <class Iterator>
    T apply(Iterator it){
       return coefs[0] * (*(it)) + coefs[1] * (*(it + 1)) + coefs[2] * (*(it + 2));
    }
};

template <class T>
struct my_coefs : public boost::array<T, 3>{
    my_coefs() {
        (*this)[0] = static_cast<T>(3.0);
        (*this)[1] = static_cast<T>(2.7);
        (*this)[2] = static_cast<T>(4.78);
    }
};

int main(){

    vector<double> my_vec(3, 9.1) ;
    typedef scale_add<double,  my_coefs<double> > my_scale_add;
    my_scale_add msa;
    double result = msa.apply(my_vec.begin() );
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

As you see, the programmer will be able to make types like my_scale_add ! This is the design solution i have for the moment. I have tried to express the "floats" as structs with a function value() that will return the number :

```
struct a1{
    typedef double type;
    static double value(){
        return 0.5;
    }
};
```

This way i put my types into typelist etc. The only problem with this is that it can get confusing and it is possible to face type redefinitions etc. But when i write something like 
    cout << a1::value() * 4.0 << endl; 
the compiler will inline it (according to some references i have).

So my question is, how can i get the behavior of the second way (a1::value() ), without having a huge programming overhead with type packing into typelists etc ? Can you propose a more efficient way to express the first code (ok, this can be considered a bad question) ? Concluding, i want to say that i am not sure if the question fits the stackoverflow, and, i am new to C++ and had to jump from what is a header file to what is template metaprogramming so i might have overlooked some information in the middle, meaning that it is possible that i am asking something trivial. Thank you in advance !

Comment: The numbers that are chosen are totally random by the way.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that all of this _works_ (i.e. actually produces better runtime performance than simple code)? To me, this question looks like you're in over your head here and making a lot of assumptions about the behaviour of the generated code that are likely to be unfounded.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't completely understand what you mean, I think the following codes may fit your requirement.

```
template<typename Container>
struct scale_add
{
     typedef typename Container::traits_type type;

     Container Impl ;
     template<typename Iterator>
     type apply( Iterator First ) {
          return std::inner_product( std::begin(Impl) , std::end(Impl) ,
                                     First , type(0) );
     }
};

template<typename K>
struct my_scale_add : public std::array<K , 3>
{
     typedef K traits_type ;

     my_scale_add() { 
          (*this)[0] = static_cast<K>( 1.0 );
          (*this)[1] = static_cast<K>( 2.0 );
          (*this)[2] = static_cast<K>( 3.0 );
     }
};

int main()
{
      std::vector<double> my_vec(3,9.1);
      scale_add<my_scale_add<double>> mObject ;

      std::cout << mObject.apply( std::begin(my_vec) ) << std::endl;

      return 0;
}
```